# Specify file to read for memory region in GDB?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I'm using gdb for arm in Linux.

I want to read memory region from file, not read from target. It looks like read target description via `set tdesc filename PATH`. I found out the function `static void require_user_regions (int from_tty)` in `memattr.c` but I don't know how to use it.

Please let me know if you have any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the memory from a running process you gotta use the procfs : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs#Linux

The file you're looking for is `/proc/[pid]/mem`

Comment: Thanks your reply, but it's not what I'm looking for, you know GDB will read file(e.i memory-map.xml) from PC and process and using later for debugging. The processing looks like read target description from PC.

Comment: So you want the actual mapping of the memory ? Have you tried looking at `/proc/[pid]/maps` ?